# Mongodb Compass running but GUI is not visible

Tags: mongodb-compass

I have installed Mongodb Compass on windows 2016 server.
When I Run it, GUI is not visible?
However, Task manager shows that it is running.

I have rebooted the machine, then also the problem is there

Please help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Uninstall MongoDB Compass from 'Programs and Features' via Control Panel

You should download 'Windows (7+)(MSI)' from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass and try to install again